# issues with login and register page php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have thoroughly researched my topic before coming here and can't seem to figure out my problem.

I have an HTML page:

```
<form role="form" action="register.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Student ID:</label>
        <input type="number" name="student_id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="register" value="register">Register</button>
</form>
<form role="form" action="login.php" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email address:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="login" value="login">Login</button>
</form>
```

This functions and communicates perfectly well with my login page written in php, it checks if the submitted email address already exists in a MySQL database. It will then point the user to a profile page and the code exits itself.

My issue is with my register page, I use the same MySQL SELECT functions that I do on my login page, to check and see if the submitted student ID or email already exists in the database and if so, will return back to the form for the user to try again:

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$student_id = $_POST['student_id'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    register($conn, $first_name, $last_name, $student_id, $email);
}
function register($conn, $first_name, $last_name, $student_id, $email) {
    $Ssql = "SELECT student_id FROM AidenLocke where student_id = '$student_id'";
    $Sresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($Sresult) > 0) {
        header('Location: form.html');
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO AidenLocke (first_name, last_name, email, student_id)
            VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$student_id')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br />" . $conn->error;
        }
        header('Location: profile.php');
    }
}
```

(I have removed my database information for security reasons but there is no connection problem)

My main issue is with the else section of the second if statement, my code does not check if the student id already exists, and regardless of what information I enter into the form, makes a new entry in to the database.

I am quite confused and hoping someone can give me a valid answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a typo in your variable when you query the database:

```
$Ssql = "SELECT student_id FROM AidenLocke where student_id = '$student_id'";
 ^^^^
$Sresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                                ^^^
```

That is, you're using `$sql` instead of `$Ssql`

Comment: Can't believe this was the only issue! Thanks :)

Comment: @user5459946 that's a good example why to use custom DB managers that hide such implementation :-)